# How should I optimize drawing a large, dynamic number of collections of vertices?

Tags: xna, xna-4.0

...or am I insane to even try?

As a novice to using bare vertices for 3d graphics, I haven't ever worked with vertex buffers and the like before.  I am guessing that I should use a dynamic buffer because my game deals with manipulating, adding and deleting primitives.  But how would I go about doing that?

So far I have stored my indices in a Triangle.cs class.  Triangles are stored in Quads (which contain the vertices that correspond to their indices), quads are stored in blocks.  In my draw method, I iterate through each block, each quad in each block, and finally each triangle, apply the appropriate texture to my effect, then call DrawUserIndexedPrimitives to draw the vertices stored in the triangle.

I'd like to use a vertex buffer because this method cannot support the scale I am going for.  I am assuming it to be dynamic.  Since my vertices and indices are stored in a collection of separate classes, though, can I still effectively use a buffer?  Is using separate buffers for each quad silly (I'm guessing it is)?  Is it feasible and effective for me to dump vertices into the buffer the first time a quad is drawn and then store where those vertices were so that I can apply that offset to that triangle's indices for successive draws?  Is there a feasible way to handle removing vertices from the buffer in this scenario (perhaps event-based shifting of index offsets in triangles)?

I apologize that these questions may be either far too novicely or too confusing/vague.  I'd be happy to provide clarification.  But as I've said, I'm new to this and I may not even know what I'm talking about...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't exactly tell what you're trying to do, but using a seperate buffer for every quad is very silly.

The golden rule in graphics programming is *batch, batch, batch*. This means to pack as much stuff into a single DrawUserIndexedPrimitives call as possible, your graphics card will love you for it.

In your case, put all of your verticies and indicies into one vertex buffer and index buffer (you might need to use more, I have no idea how many verticies we're talking about). Whenever the user changes one of the primatives, regenerate the entire buffer. If you really have a lot of primatives, split them up into multiple buffers and on only regenerate the ones you need when the user changes something.

The most important thing is to minimize the amount of 'DrawUserIndexedPrimitives' calls, those things have a **lot** of overhead, you could easily make your game on the order of 20x faster.
Graphics cards are pipelines, they like being given a big chunk of data for them to eat away at. What you're doing by giving it one triangle at a time is like forcing a large-scale car factory to only make one car at a time. Where they can't start on building the next car before the last one is finished.

Anyway good luck, and feel free to ask any questions.

Comment: If I implement a buffer, I won't have to call DrawUserIndexedPrimitives, but instead a more efficient method, yes?

Also, I understand what you are saying as far as batching.  As far as I can tell there's no real logical way to divide up my primitives, but I could possibly throw them all in one large array.  There are only two issues I foresee: how to effectively keep track of indices when faces are removed from the buffer (should I recalculate all of them?) and how to texture faces independently (I could probably write a shader for this... maybe... there are a ton of textures...)

Comment: Well, the problem isn't the DrawUserIndexedPrimitives, any Draw... call is slow. The problem is the sheer amount of times you make that call. Recalculate all of the indices, it shouldn't be much more than just a shift. If you're really fussed there are faster more elaborate alternatives, but they probably aren't necessary. As for the textures, use a texture atlas. This is where you make one giant texture with all of the textures inside it. Then you can get the right texture just by changing the texcoords.

Comment: Interesting.  Care to elaborate on texture coordinates?  Insofar I have only really been guessing about how to use them.  When I create a VertexPositionNormalTexture, does the texture coordinate parameter correspond with a position on the texture I pass to the shader, or a position on the model's face?  This has caused me some confusion.  Also, the primitives I make vary in size and I want their appropriate texture to stretch across each face.  I feel like using an atlas would break that.

Comment: Sure. It corresponds to a position on the texture, like usual. Let me give you an example: say you had a quad which would normally have the texcoords [0 0], [0 1], [1 1] and [1, 0]. If the texture you wanted to sample from was actually part of an atlas, sitting in the top right corner from [.5 0] to [1 .5]. Your new texcoords would be transformed to only access this subtexture, so in this case [.5 0], [.5 .5], [1 .5], [1 0]. Stretching the texture should be no problem, do you mean tiling (repeating) the texture? That isn't as easy. May I ask what you're making by the way?

Comment: Here's a screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/Nf7Az.png  

It's a sphere made of frustum blocks.  As you can see I'm scaling the block textures to fit the various shapes of the faces.  What you're saying makes sense and I'm pretty sure I can apply it to this situation.  If I make a texture atlas and select the appropriate coordinates of the correct texture, it should still scale to the whole face, correct?  I'm pretty sure I understand now, thank you very much for your help.